# Finding a cosine-like function passing through five points

Tags: functions, polynomials

I need to find a polynomial representation -- or other type of function representation -- of a function passing through 5 given points.

I am only interested in its value between -Pi/2 and Pi/2. It is similar to a skewed cosine: it is zero at -Pi/2 and Pi/2 and its value will be less than 1 but greater than zero with a single maxima of one in the interval. The maxima is one of the given points; it does not necessarily occur at 0. The other two given points are where the function should hit 0.5 on the two sides of the maxima.

I'm looking for a good approach here. I could stitch together two beziers. I could solve for a particular quartic from the five points, etc.

Comment: As you are given 2 roots, you only need to solve for a cubic, not a quintic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you might want to use trigonometric interpolation (https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TrigonometricFittingAndInterpolation/)

But you can use Lagrange polynomials as well (solving for the quartic from 5 points) (https://trkern.github.io/lagrange2.html)